# It is possible to make a requestFullscreen () in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing code that generates a `<iframe>` so that other people can put this code on their sites, one of the functions of this `<iframe>` is `requestFullscreen();`

This request is working optimally, but it does not allow to do this in a cross domain.

Below is an image representing the structure of the elements.

[image]

PHP main page code

```
<div id="alpha">
    <a href="#">A simple full screen template</a>
</div>
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function(){
        var screenresize = $('#alpha').get(0);
        screenresize.requestFullscreen();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Cross domain HTML/PHP code

```
<iframe src="http://experimental.devz/iframe.php"></iframe>
```

I know it's possible to do this because youtube also works the same way, although your code is scrambled, I know it does it or similar.

Comment: Show your code, not just an image of the desired structure.

Comment: One moment I'll rewrite the code, because mine is over 2000, I'll assemble a simple verion of it.

Comment: Ok i finished the code so i will be updating the question so that it appears, thank you for your attention.

Comment: Alright, I updated the question code.

Comment: I think your code will make the main page full screen, not the iframe. To make the iframe full screen, the request has to come from JavaScript inside the iframe.

Comment: As I was so stupid, you solved my problem, thank you so much, just add ```allowfullscreen="true "``` to ```<iframe>``` to make it work properly, thank you, now I can continue my suspended code.

Comment: Happy to help you. Please accept my answer for the clarity of further readers.

Comment: Feel free to reply to this post so I can rate it as a correct answer. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need an iframe with the attribute **allow="fullscreen"**

> Set **allow="fullscreen** can activate fullscreen mode by calling the requestFullscreen() method.

See this [iframe: The Inline Frame element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Example:

```
<iframe allow="fullscreen" src="http://experimental.devz/iframe.php"></iframe>
```